# Can't increment a variable in bash. Scope mistake? Syntax?

Tags: bash

I have read over a dozen solution posts on this issue, yet my problem remains.  Why can I not increment the `HITS` or `MISSES` variable in my code? I just can't see the mistake:

```
MISSES=0
HITS=0
for fName in *.dat; do (
    if grep -q "hit" "$fName"; then 
        echo "$fName hit";
        ((HITS++));
        else
        echo "$fName miss";
        ((MISSES++));
        fi;
    );done
```

I just started familiarizing myself with bash, so I know very little thus far.

Answer (score 2):

`(...)` runs its contents in a subshell, which means any changes to variables in the subshell are not visible after the subshell exits. You can omit them:

```
for fName in *.dat; do
  if grep -q hit "$fName"; then
    echo "$fName hit"
    ((HITS++))
  else
    echo "$fName miss"
    ((MISSES++))
  fi
done
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  You answered in 2 mins what I've been trying to figure out for about an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like:
HITS=$(($HITS+1));